# Trying to return a variable mid script to my template

Tags: python, django

I am wanting to display a dynamic count on my home.html. While my for loop is running I would like my Template to display the current count of the loop. Is this possible, and if so what is this process called so I can read up on it.

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% if output >= 1 %}
         <p>Current count is {output}</p>
    {%endif%}
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def page_objects(request):
     output = 0
     for row in c:
          output = output + 1 
          return output
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('views', views.page_objects, name = 'page_objects')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution come to my mind is use web socket which was widely adopted in web-chat. However it is a little complicated just for this function only. You may refer to Django Channels on how to realize it. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: An alternative way is to create a html page which refreshes periodically by : setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod); The server throw the count periodically to the database or a session variable to be read by the client. This will be much easier than using Channels.